# Windows Azure Traffic Manager Basics

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm working on azure project and came across Azure Traffic Manager. Could someone please help me few question below:

1. Is Traffic Manager same as load balancer?
2. Do we need to create Traffic Manager manually or created automatically on webrole deploy.
3. How do I configure Traffic Manager with new Azure Mgt. Portal?
4. What is the main purpose of Poll State, as it says offline but I can still access using trafic manager url.
5. When we get proper CNAME, should CNAME point to this Traffic manager or url provided on Cloud Service > Dashboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Traffic Manager same as load balancer?

> > It can be used for failover or load balancing, although only in a round robin way.
> >     Have a look here.
> >
> > https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/

Do we need to create Traffic Manager manually or created automatically on webrole deploy.
You need to create it manually.

How do I configure Traffic Manager with new Azure Mgt. Portal?

> > Currently I believe you can only do it in the old portal.

What is the main purpose of Poll State, as it says offline but I can still access using trafic manager url.

> > Again easier to read this.
> >     https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-overview/

When we get proper CNAME, should CNAME point to this Traffic manager or url provided on Cloud Service > Dashboard?

> > If you want to use traffic manager to manage the traffic you point your CName to the traffic manager url.